Chrome/Safari input auto zoom out while blur or deseleted
i have a react application, where I'm taking a input field,
on mobile device ,
there is a auto zoom feature to highlight the zoom
one way i found was to use font size :16px
input{ font-size:16px;}
my question is there a way to auto zoom out if i deselect the input field and screen zooms out?this breaks the screen
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />

Can you provide more info/explanation, I didn't understand your question correctly

i meant like in how chrome and safari on mobile devices
if input font size is lesser than 16px , it auto zooms, is there a way to auto zoom out when i  deselect or blur the input?
